# It's normal to test model on independent data after cross validation

Tags: r

I want to perform a random forest model, so I split my data into 70% for the train and 30% for the test. I applied a cross validation procedure on my train data (70%) and obtained a precision for the cross validation. After that, I test my model on the test data (30%), then I have another clarification.

So, I want to know if this is a good approach to test the robustness of my model, and what is the interpretation of these two precision.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since your question is about the proper way to do Statistics, rather than programming, it would be a better fit for [stats.se]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to perform Cross-Validation when building a RF model, as RF calculates its own CV score knows as OOB score. In fact, the results that you get from the model (the confusion matrix at `model_name$confusion`) is based on the OOB scores.

You can use the OOB scores (and the various metrics derived from them, such as Precision, Recall, etc.) to select a model from a list of models (for ex. models with different parameters / arguments) and then use the test data to check if the selected model generalises well.